# Angular 2 : HTTP Request

Tags: angular, angular-cli

New to Angular 2 and HTTP need to know CRUD operations using HTTP Request. Below are my queries

1. As per angular tutorials we need to use POST to send data, GET to get data, PUT to update data and DELETE to deleted data.
2. but some of my colleagues suggested me to use POST for all CRUD operations. POST is a secured way to communicate as it sends data in a body
3. GET sends data in URL which is not a secured way
4. PUT and DELETE is not recommended to use.

if all of my above points are true then how to use POST for all CRUD operations.

Comment: You can very well use POST for update, delete, save. That's how I do it :)

Comment: Can you please help me with any reference link on how to use POST for CRUD operations

Comment: If you don't use HTTPS both methods POST and GET (and the others too) are equally insecure. Some old Devs claim that some HTTP proxies don't work well with not in heavy use HTTP methods (DELETE, PUT) but I never came across that problem

Comment: I also highly recommend this rest API specification: http://jsonapi.org/